# QGIS Server Not working

Tags: apache, qgis

alright guys I have been stuck on this for the last 2,3 days I have searched online for a solution, I have tried re-installing QGIS Server. But I can't get the Digital Maps to Load.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2.

I install packages using the `osgeo4w-setup` file.

After installing when I browse to `localhost:9090/` I can see the following.

[image]

Then the next step when I browse to:

```
http://localhost:9090/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=d:/dgmps/GIS.qgs
```

I get following error:

[image]

In the Apache Error Log files I am getting this:

First I was getting this error:

```
[Sat Mar 07 00:25:40 2015] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Sat Mar 07 00:25:40 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
```

So I followed all links [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74543/how-to-get-qgis-server-getcapabilities-working-on-windows) , [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43843/qgis-server-internal-server-error-os-109the-pipe-has-been-ended-mod-fcgid) I could find online, after that I was getting the following error:

The Error Log in Apache Error Log is:

```
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified\r
[Sat Mar 07 23:24:18 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named site\r
```

Anybody know the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for an answer, but it might still help someone:

- copy all .dll from osgeo4w/bin to osgeo4w/apps/qgis/bin
- copy all .py from osgeo4w/apps/python/Lib to osgeo4w/apps/qgis/bin
- copy folder "encodings" from osgeo4w/apps/python/Lib to osgeo4w/apps/qgis/bin

amend the httpd.conf file as follows (I'm using the 64 bit, so be careful when copy-pasting):

```
DefaultInitEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\lib;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
DefaultInitEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis"
DefaultInitEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt4\plugins"
```